How to forecast from fable::TSLM with nonstandard specials?
I am trying to forecast time series with a model containing natural spline trend - by tidyverts package system in R.
Since fable package supports only linear splines (through one of its exogenous regressors function trend) I have to use a third-party function ns() from package splines in the model formula. The function ns(time, df) creates a model matrix with orthogonal basis function values. This makes a problem when extending matrix from training to validation period. Supplying new values to time argument does not preserve continuity of training and validation model matrices.
The same problem arises with function stats::poly. However, poly allows to return non-orthogonalized basis model matrix by setting argument raw = TRUE. This option is not available in ns.
The following example illustrates the problem of forecasting with fable::forecast.TSLM method (the same issue occurs with other model functions that allows for inclusion of exogenous regressors)
library(ggplot2)
# training data set
train <- c(11, 14, 17, 19, 21) |>
  ts() |>
  tsibble::as_tsibble()
# training and forecast
fore <- train |>
  fabletools::model(
    poly = fable::TSLM(value ~ poly(index, 2)),
    polyraw = fable::TSLM(value ~ poly(index, 2, raw = TRUE)),
    ns = fable::TSLM(value ~ splines::ns(index, df = 2))
  ) |>
  fabletools::forecast(h = 3)
# plot
ggplot() + aes(x = index) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value), data = train) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .mean, color = .model, group = .model), data = fore)

trend forecast
For the purpose of natural spline model matrix extension there is a method splines::predict.ns. I need this to be used by forecast.TSLM.
The support package fabletools allows users to extend models by defining their own "specials" (functions to return design matrix for specific model component). I need help with making a new special such as trend(), lets call it nstrend, that could be used in model formula required my function fable::TSLM during model fitting (use ns to make model matrix) and utilized by fable::forecast.TSLM to calculate forecasts (use predict.ns to make model matrix).
So my question is, how to define nstrend() so that it could be used with fable package to predict natural spline trend.
